# ERROR MY-010270 Server Bind on unix socket: input/output error Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows, docker, phpstorm

I tried creating a MySQL image using Docker in PhpStorm. But it's giving me this:

> ERROR MY-010270 Server Bind on unix socket: input/output error

Comment: Please add details. What server version, what OS, on which step does it occur...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker on Windows 10 and you mount `/var/lib/mysql` as volume, this happens because windows doesn't support unix sockets.

Maybe is not the best solution, but as a workaround you can change the position in the filesystem of mysql socket editing `my.cnf` (mysql config file).

in `/etc/my.cnf` edit as follow:

```
[client]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

Answer (score 0):

@Davide is right. But for a docker usage it is easier to set

switch `--socket=/tmp/mysql.sock` when starting the server.

(The problem is related just for Windows host.)